# Is it possible to overwrite the code segment with a normal C++ program under Windows XP?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, assembly

I'm currently investigating a windows crash dump and the Visual Studio debugger shows me an "illegal instruction `0xC000001D`" when opening the dump file. The code position it shows this error shows a disassembly along the following example:

```
 void g(int x) {
 00401E80  push        ebp  
 00401E81  mov         ebp,esp 
    if(x > 20) {
 00401E83  cmp         dword ptr [x],14h 
 00401E87  jle         g+14h (401E94h) 
        x *= 4;
>00401E89  db          0fh  // illegal instruction here
 00401E8A  db          0fh  
 00401E8B  xadd        eax,esp 
 00401E8E  add         cl,byte ptr [ecx+9EB0845h] 
        x += 42;
 00401E94  mov         ecx,dword ptr [x]
 ...
```

I manually created the above example in the debugger by overwriting the function code with some invalid values in the debuggers memory window, but the crash dump I am investigation shows the same `db 0fh` entry, apparently indicating an invalid instruction. The code is also similar to what my dump file displays in that the instructions prior to the invalid instruction all seem valid and matching the source code.

Now **the question is** *is it possible at all in a normally compiled C++ program - that does not mess around with memory page access restrictions - (Visual C++ 2005 on Windows XP) to mess up the code segment of the process?*

If I try to write to the function address in my example above from code, I always get an Access Violation, that is the code segment memory page appears to be write protected.

```
{
    void* fnAddr = &g; // non-portable but OK in VC++
    unsigned int x = 0xDEADBEEF;
    // Simulate memory corruption: Try to write something to the code segment:
    memcpy((char*)fnAddr+4, &x, sizeof(x)); // generated 0xC0000005 Access Violation
    g(42); // call messed up function - never get here
}
```

Do you know of any situation where it would in fact be possible to inadvertently overwrite something in the code segment?

I should add that the real program is lots more complicated, with lots of virtual functions, some member function pointers, etc. etc. and the problem is sadly not reproducible, we only currently have this one dump file that looks fine otherwise. -- Still, the dump file displays an illegal instruction in the code segment and I would not have thought it possible to mess up the code segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the memory pages that contain code are write protected.  This kind of damage could only occur at process initialization time.  But the more likely source is soft RAM errors.  Ask your customer to run a RAM test program.  Consider file damage is the error is repeatable.

Comment: The files seem OK. RAM error seems unlikely, but we'll test. Maybe the dump file is not showing me what I think its showing me.

Answer (score 1):

By default `.text` section has `RX` access rights. Howerer, using `VirtualProtect` you can obtain write rigths for these memory pages. But, take a look at this..

I suppose this should be the code :

```
code:00401000 55                                push    ebp
code:00401001 89 E5                             mov     ebp, esp
code:00401003 81 7D 08 14 00 00+                cmp     dword ptr [ebp+8], 14h
code:0040100A 7E 0B                             jle     short loc_401017
code:0040100A                   ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
code:0040100C 0F                                db  0Fh // here should be x += 10.5; ??
code:0040100D 0F                                db  0Fh 
code:0040100E 0F                                db  0Fh 
code:0040100F                   ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
code:0040100F C1 E0 02                          shl     eax, 2 ; //x *= 4
code:00401012
code:00401012                   loc_401012:
code:00401012 89 45 08                          mov     [ebp+8], eax // save x
code:00401015 EB 09                             jmp     short near ptr unk_401020
code:00401017                   ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
code:00401017
code:00401017                   loc_401017:                             ; CODE XREF: code:0040100Aj
code:00401017 8B 4D 08                          mov     ecx, [ebp+8]
```

If I've guessed the opcodes, then the *missing* part should add 10.5 to eax, something not quite possible. Can you try for curiosity to make it

```
if (x > 20){
      x *= 4; 
      x += 40;
};
```

Can you also post the whole `g(int)` function together with its asm listing? (if possible, with binary opcode values as in mine example).

Comment: ruslik - the opcodes I presented here were created by me overwriting memory in the debuggers memory view. At the time of writing of this post I didn't have access to the original dump listing, so I used my test program with "manually" messed up memory.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause for your difficulty is that you have overflowed a local variable (say a string) and overwritten your stack frame.  When the subroutine exits, it will pop off the return address from the stack and begin executing whatever instructions it finds there.  This is the mechanism that gets exploited with a buffer overflow attack.

Comment: Stack overflow cannot modify code section. And there are invalid opcodes in that function.

Comment: x86 uses variable-length instructions, and there can be padding between functions. You can't assume that any pointer into the code segment will point to a valid instruction.

Comment: The mem addr we are at (00401E89 in the example above, some 0061FF.. in my dump file) appeard to be a valid address in that (as in the example above) all asm instructions *prior* to the faulty instruction were valid opcodes and what's more were the actual opcodes of correct sourcecode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in situations where part of the code segment has been made writeable by the application, for example in Java JITs, where the Java bytecode is compiled on the fly to native code.

Comment: The answer should have started with "No", since the question was: *is it possible at all in a normally compiled C++ program - that does not mess around with memory page access restrictions -to mess up the code segment of the process?*